# Padding in a div where other divs are floated

Tags: css, html, css-float, padding

Here is the JSFiddle link:

http://jsfiddle.net/stapiagutierrez/48yGU/34/

When I use `padding: 10px;` on the `#middle` div, I thought it would make the contained divs inside become smaller to fit the padding.

This is partially true, it's pushed from the top and left/right, but it's overflowing from the bottom.

Any explanation for this, and a solution for this common case? So far, I've used `overflow: hidden;` but this feels like a hack. But maybe since I'm new to CSS this **is** how you're supposed to handle it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add clear after the floats like this: http://jsfiddle.net/48yGU/38/
Edit: the reason its overflowing from the bottom is because float does not have size. so the container thinks there is nothing there and just draws the padding on both sides (thats why it looks line height). what clear does is it sticks to bottom of floats and have size, so its pushing the container bottom to the bottom of the floats.

Answer (score 0):

It's because the floated DIVS are positioned out of the normal flow, in which padding would normally consider the height and width of contained elements.

Comment: Can you elaborate please? What is normal flow? Does floating a div make it not have a height and width anymore?

Comment: @Sergio, The Normal Flow is just a fancy term for how things are normally displayed. The DIV does have a height and width, but the containing div doesn't see the DIVS as being part of it.